# ArcGIS Javascript API - Label renderers from Map Service for a FeatureLayer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I wonder if it is possible to use the labels renderers defined in a .mxd published as a Map Service (Feature Access enabled) for a FeatureLayer with the javascript API v4.3 just like it works with the geometry renderer?

I define a featureLayer like this:

```
var organismesLayer = new FeatureLayer({
  url: "https://infogeo.education.gouv.qc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/SandBox_Maxime/GDUNO/MapServer/1",
  labelsVisible: true
});
```

In the map, I see the layer style is the same than in the .mxd, but the labels are not visible. Do I have to define the LabelClass manually in the javascript code?

Is there a way to get the label renderers from the Map Service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With version 4.3 there is not yet support for labeling in 2D. Labeling is only supported in 3D SceneViews so far.

See the "Known Limitations" in https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#labelsVisible